# CSS, can i use two different colors in one table cell? (for example dark purple and light purple)

Tags: html, css

Doen anyone know how to use two colors in one table cell (td) and how to let them overflow inc each other?

For examble. For my website (www.ericversteeg.nl) i want to use in my guest book title columns light purple in the top of the cell and dark purple in the bottom.

I think i have to assign a class in the td.

But how do i make my class in CSS?

Greetings Eric

Comment: you can use an inline code block to specify your `<td class="multi_purple">`  just use the backticks (typically to the left of the 1 key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tool quite helpfull: [CSS3 Gradient Generator](http://gradients.glrzad.com/). The code it produces isn't the most beutiful but it works!

Comment: allright i understand, with the link i can make a background image. But as you can see on my website i have two layouts so the td's dont have the same width. How do i solve that in CSS, with repeat?

Answer (score 2):

The [CSS 3 drafts](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/) introduce gradient colours.

e.g.

```
background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(63,76,107,1) 0%,rgba(63,76,107,1) 100%);
```

Note that [browser support is not universal](http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this.  The first is to have a div on top and a div on bottom, each with the different color.

```
<td class="multi_purple">
    <div class="top">
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
    </div>
</td>
```

and style the two divs with their respective colors.

A "better" option would be to just use a background image of the right colors.  This will be cross browser supported, but doesnt do well if your table grows or shrinks in size.

The *newest* option would be to add a gradient.  check out http://www.css3please.com to see the syntax for this.

but its something like this

```
background-color: #444444;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999);
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999);
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999);
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #444444, #999999);
```

with of course your purple shades in place.

This degrades into a solid color for browsers that dont support gradients (lookin at you ie 6/7?)

Comment: allright i understand, with the link i can make a background image. But as you can see on my website i have two layouts so the td's dont have the same width. How do i solve that in CSS, with repeat?

Comment: style the background on the `tr` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a background gradient like was suggested, or using a background image that has both colors in it.

If you know that your cells are going to be say, 30px tall, make a 30px tall by 1px wide image that is split where you want it, and have both colors in it. Then using css:

```
td {
  background-image: url(colors.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

To tile it horizontally, thus getting the effect you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/4NXRx/2/

It uses a background gradient and you don't need to call any image resources. You also don't have to worry about updating the image.

There's a back-up color for browsers that don't support gradients. It's an effect that isn't crucial to all visitors, so it's no big deal if some visitors don't see a gradient.

Note, that I have made the stops at 49%, so there is no gradual change. I don't know if that's what you want. Obviously, you'll have to choose nicer colors.

```
table td {
padding: 10px;

background-color: #CEC3FA;
background-image: linear-gradient(49%, #CEC3FA 8%, #B9AAD1 51%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(49%, #CEC3FA 8%, #B9AAD1 51%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(49%, #CEC3FA 8%, #B9AAD1 51%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(49%, #CEC3FA 8%, #B9AAD1 51%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(49%, #CEC3FA 8%, #B9AAD1 51%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    right 49%,
    right 50%,
    color-stop(0.08, #CEC3FA),
    color-stop(0.51, #B9AAD1)
);
```